# send an email using HTML+Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email

As I run this code I am able to send an email, but I am not able to load the body of HTML into Email body, please help me to load the html body into email body using Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendMail() {
        var link = 'mailto:hello@domain.com?subject=Message from ' +document.getElementById('email_address').value +'&body='+document.getElementById('email_address').value;
        window.location.href = link;
    }
</script>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" id="email_address" name="name" placeholder="Enter your email address..." required>
        <button onclick="sendMail()">Send Email</button>
        <br>
        MALE:
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Package" value="yes">Yes </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Package" value="no">No  </td>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't. It's not possible to do that from within the HTML document.

Comment: oh thanks.. then How could I do this? do you have any ready made code? please help me its quite urgent.. I will be happy to thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use jQuery.  It is the de facto standard when working with Javascript.

When that is done then you can simply use $("body").html() to fetch the html for the document.

Comment: very thanks... I am new to Jquery could you please let me know how do use that in this situation? how do I call Jquery (what function, where to use, etc..), thanks again for help

Comment: That's wont turn the E-Mail into a HTML message though. It'll just show the HTML as plain text. Which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: I thought he just wants the html body as text?  user2481507 could you clarify the question a bit.  Do you want the html simply as text or do you want to send an html email?

Comment: I am fine even it is a plain text, but html body should be inserted into Email body

Comment: Then the jquery solution I mention above should be sufficient, jQuery is the standard way to use Javascript.  To use it include the jQuery library with a script tag into the html page and then call $("body").html() to fetch the html body.  To learn to use it start here:  http://try.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create a HTML E-Mail (sent by the user) from within a HTML document.

You can only pre-populate the user's "message" field with plain-text content.

You can fetch the HTML body as @user357320 suggests, but that will only get you the plain-text representation of the HTML tags, like

```
<html>
 <body>
....
```

and not an actual real HTML E-Mail.

Comment: <form method="post" action="mailto:shidy@cant.com"> using this I can send email with HTML body in email body but it  is not working in IE late versions...

Answer (score 0):

You need one server side language to send email. There are many.
Below is the code to send email using PHP

```
<?php
 $to = "recipient@domain.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
?>
```

You need to do the following (irrespective of any server-side language)
1. Fetch the data and validate using JavaScript
2. Send the data (using POST or GET) to the server-side language
3. At server-side you need to fetch the data from Request Object
4. Use those data to prepare your email
5. Send email

---

Referring your snippet
HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" action="sendemail.php">
<input type="hidden" id="email_address" name="name" placeholder="Enter your email
address..." required>
<input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
<br>
 MALE:
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="Package" value="yes">Yes </td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="Package" value="no">No  </td>
 </tr>
  </form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
  $package = $_REQUEST['Package'];   // It is the name you give to input elements
  ...
  ...  // Same code as above (prepare email and sent)
  ...
?>
```

Before you submit the code to php, you can validate it.
This will give you the idea about the flow